# Can't get types to match in F# Functions

Tags: types, f#, matching

I'm trying to convert a string into a list of roman digit types. But I don't understand how seq.map works.

Changing the types in the charromdig.

```
let charRomDig c:RomDig = 
    match c with
        | "I" -> I
        | "V" -> V
        | "X" -> X
        | _ -> I

let toUpper (s:string) = 
    s.ToUpper()

let strToRom (str:string): RomNum = 
    let res = toUpper str
    let xTimes2 =
    res
    |> Seq.map(charRomDig)
    romL

let res = strToRom "XI"
```

I want it to successfully show a list of converted roman digits.

But I get the following:

```
'char -> 'a'
but given a
    'string -> RomDig'
The type 'char' does not match the type 'string'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Seq.map is expecting a char to RomDig, but instead receives a function which takes a string to romDig. This sounds about right because it looks like your map maps strings to RomDig. In the future make sure to include your type definitions, as it makes helping you much easier. Here in charRomDig I noticed that your matches are "I" "V" and "X" instead of 'I' 'V' and 'X' . When you consider a string as a seq of individual characters the match needs to also be chars.

```
type RomDig = I | V | X 
type RomNum = RomDig seq //equivalent to seq<RomDig> 
let charRomDig c:RomDig = match c with | 'I' -> I | 'V' -> V | 'X' -> X | _ -> I
let strToRom (str:string): RomNum = 
    let xTimes2 = str |> Seq.map(charRomDig)
    xTimes2

let XI = strToRom "XI"
```